# Do I need to create root, swap, and home partitions in a specific order?

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot

I've just installed Win7 and left enough space on my hdd for Ubuntu. I'd like to create a root partition, a swap partition and a home partition. Do I need to create them in a special order, at a special location and most importantly: which one should be primary and which one logical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no particular recommended order. Also, it is not required to have a special type for partitions (you can make them logical or primary however you want; the number of primary partitions is restricted to, I think, 4). 
You can read [here](http://www.nyx.net/~sgjoen/disk.html) about strategies on how to create your multidisk system.

Answer (score 2):

I guess not... But i always create the "/" partition, then home partition and last the swap...

Comment: That's the wonderful freedom of gnu/linux based systems.  I've never had the arrogance to say 'my way is right, yours is wrong'.  That is the Windows way.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider just letting the live-DVD follow the defaults unless you have a special reason for wanting home and root on separate partitions.  That course is no longer used by most Ubuntu folk these days.

Comment: Why is that so?

Comment: Mainly because we are using safe backups automatically and using the cloud for important stuff.  It just isn't important any more to have personal stuff on a different partition so this has become the default on the Ubuntu install.  Feel free to stick with what you like.